# Are crypts "rerolled" if I logout while looking for Leoric's crown?

Tags: diablo-iii

While on the quest for King Leoric's crown, I had to logout twice, each time after exploring a different crypt. Is it possible that the correct crypt has been rerolled, meaning that I have to explore again those two, or I can skip those and keep going on my quest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nicks answer confused me, so I just tested it:

Leaving the game doesn't leave anything intact, it resets your progress. To be more precise: You should look at playing Diablo III as playing a hosted session of a certain quest, with the bonus ability that quests transition into each other seamlessly. You can only start or resume the game from the beginning of a sub-quest within one of the main quests.

When you leave the game and then re-enter using the "Resume game" button, the gamestate is reset: The map is put back into a state where nothing is revealed, the random dungeons that appear on the overworld are shuffled again (this means that you can effectively farm a certain location  until you've gone through all possible dungeons/events that can appear in that area), enemies respawn, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply "Leave Game", exiting to the hero screen, your game remains intact if you "Resume".

Relogging however, will completely remove your existing game; the "Resume Game" button simply creates a new game instance and drops you at the start of whichever zone.